# Sync Framework architecture for offline app

Tags: architecture, offline, microsoft-sync-framework, azure-sql-database

I am in the process of designing a new application which consists of a central SQL-Azure database and many (potentially +2000) remote clients [kiosks]. I need to synchronise a simple (10 table) local SQL CE databases with the Azure DB and envisage that the synchronisation will need to take place at least once a day - there may not be a huge number of transactions that need to be applied to the kiosks in each sync i.e. a couple of inserts, a couple of updates (quite frequently no changes will need to be applied); at present I also only envisage it will be master > client updates not bidirectional. I have considered client - client synchronisation to help with scalability on the server however unfortunately my client has indicated that this may not possible since kiosks only have 3G connections and do not participate in a LAN.

To achieve this I am looking to use the MS Sync Framework which works really well, however I have concerns regarding potential contention and also for performance when many clients may simultaneously connect to the central Azure DB at approx the same time. I can see two possible solutions to this:

1) Have a server side scheduling work queue which calls a WCF service on the client which would initiate the synchronisation from the client. This feels a little over engineered to me and adds an added degree of complexity to the solution.

2) Configure each client or batches of clients to synchronise at a different time of day - this is workable but could become an admin. burden.

...or, am I over thinking the problem/is the problem not existent and the scale of transactions manageable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i posted a reply to your question in the Sync Fx forums but ill post it here anyway:

rather than having each client connect to the Azure DB directly, i would suggest building an Azure-based sync service. The Sync Fx team has sample for doing this at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/10/07/windows-azure-sync-service-demo-available-for-download.aspx

now regarding your Atom/OData/Non-MS platform clients, Sync Fx v4 CTP has built functionalities around OData (but not part of the OData itself) and has samples for Silverlight, Windows Phone and other clients. Unfortunately, the release has been postponed but the CTP bits will instead be released as code samples (instead of a product release).

Another option in CTP is the OData Reference Caching, check it out at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/04/13/reference-data-caching-walkthrough.aspx

Using the sample Azure Sync Service, you can easily tailor fit it to a SQL CE - Azure Sync Service - SQL Azure synch. You just need to size the average size of your synch and duration so you can spread out the synching of the 2000 clients.

another option you may explore is peer-to-peer synching.

if you have kiosks located and connected to each other, you can have one kiosk sync with Azure and have the other kiosks sync to that kiosk.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. Marking this as the answer and referring any interested parties to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/syncdevdiscussions/thread/6526bbd7-2479-4a7d-b7f5-fd6326d92933?prof=required